# Access Data from SQL Server 2008 Authentication Issues

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect to SQL Server. using this peice of code

```
public static String getDBConnection()
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder csBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        csBuilder.InitialCatalog = "AdDatabase";
        csBuilder.DataSource = "JAWADAMJAD-PC\\SQLEXPRESS";
        csBuilder.UserID = "Jawad";
        csBuilder.Password = "123456";

         return csBuilder.ConnectionString;
    }
```

I have added this user name via SQL Server Managment Console. I still cannot figure out why I am not able to connect to SQL Server. Do I have to do anything else to connect successfully?
If so what is that?
Please HELP!!! I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008.

I am getting the following exception

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'Jawad'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at AdServiceNew.Service1.initDB() in C:\Users\OZI TECH\Desktop\AdServiceNew\AdServiceNew\AdServiceNew\Service1.asmx.cs:line 57
```

I went to SERVER Logs and it says

```
An attempt to login as SQL Authentication Failed. Server is configured for windows authentication only.
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: What indication do you have that this isn't successful?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the exception, I have added it into Question. Please review

Comment: Are you able to login into SSMS with the above credentials?

Comment: No. Only windows authentication. Logs says
An attempt to login as SQL Authentication Failed. Server is configured for windows authentication only.

Comment: in management console:
Server->Properties/Security
then select SQL Server And Windows Authentication mode
Then also check if the login has mapping to proper databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only Windows Authentication mode, then you need to set the Integrated Security option to true and get rid of the User and Password..

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder =
  new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Data Source"] = "(local)";
builder["integrated Security"] = true;
builder["Initial Catalog"] = "AdventureWorks;NewValue=Bad";
Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString);

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx for more info

Comment: It is a solution and the solution by Yaugen Vlasau also worked. Thanks